# Converting usage of wireless card to access point in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-access-point, connection-sharing

I buy a [D-Link wireless card](http://www.dlink.com.au/products/?pid=791) ,I want to know can I use it instead of an access point.I have also a Asus ADSL router for connecting to internet. I want to share internet whit my wireless card and use internet in my laptop, teblet, mobile phone,... .

please help me ?

any solution for doing?